# How to make map for a nested function?

Tags: python

My intention was to mutate the list without using return. So my apporach was to create a helperfunction to modify the value and then map it to the whole list. However, map only consumes one function and one string. Thus I got stuck. Sorry for any inconvinece or misunderstanding

I have a list and two boundaries where lower boundary will replace any number below it in the list while upper boundary also replace number above it in the list.

```
def help(values,lower,upper):
    def abc(value):
            if value <= 100:
                value = 100
            elif value >= 0:
                value = 0
            else:
                value
    list(map (abc, values))
```

For example, give `A=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` with lower boundary of 2 and upper boundary of 8. It should return a list of:

```
[2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
```

The process of check will be like

```
A=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
check.expect("Function",help(A,2,8),None)
check.expect("List",help(A,2,8)[2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8])
```

Comment: Well for starters, your `help` function doesn't return anything, so it will implicitly return `None`. Similarly, your `abc` function inside `help` doesn't return anything, so it will return `None`. Why is `abc` inside `help` to begin with?

Comment: Please show an actual call of `help()` rather than describing it in words.

Comment: Also note that you never use `lower` or `upper` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use just a list-comprehension that sets element based on conditions:

```
def rreplace(lst, l, u):
    return [l if x < l else u if x > u else x for x in lst]

A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(rreplace(A, 2, 8))

# [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```